# name packages and classes with letters

Tags: java

**What is the point of naming classes and packages with letters?**
Those classes were decompiled.

It can be some kind of protection?

[image]

Comment: Yes. It prevents you from making sense of code that you shouldn't decompile. It can also be used to reduce the size of the classes and jar files, which is useful when they need to be downloaded and stored on phones, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the point of naming classes and packages with letters?

The code you are decompiling has been obfuscated to make it harder to reverse engineer.

The point is to prevent you knowing what the real package, class, method, etc names are.  Because the real names would give you clues to help you understand the code.